# Check with Saxon-JS 2.1 if a DOM classList contains a specific class

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0, saxon-js

Saxon-JS enables not only to run XSLT in the browser but also to read and write HTML content. With JavaScript, checking if a class 'edited' is contained by an elements class list can be done by

```
document.getElementById(id).classList.contains('edited')
```

but how to achieve this with Saxon-JS 2.1?

Possible ways seem to be

`ixsl:get($node, 'class')` but I don't know how to specify the node by id (and this would return the whole class list)

`ixsl:eval('document.getElementById({$id}).classList.contains('edited')')` but I suppose using {$id} isn't supported and 'edited' uses apostrophes which are already in use for both containing the eval parameter and the whole xpath statement (not included here). So both single and double apostrophes can't be used.

`ixsl:eval(document.getElementById('+$id+').classList.contains('+$class+')')` here I get an error stating that "arithmetic operator is not defined for arguments of types xs:string".

`ixsl:eval(concat('document.getElementById(',$id,').classList.contains(',$class,')'))` but even this doesn't work. It gets compiled into sef but on runtime an error "cannot read property of null" occurs.

I'm aware that I could write a JavaScript function into the HTML page and call that own function, but I want to accomplish it in the XSLT script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return any XML element that matches that condition, you could just use a standard XPath expression:

```
//*[@id eq $id][contains-token(@class, 'edited')]
```

See: [fn:contains-token](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!functions/fn/contains-token)

Comment: I thougt that the content of the live HTML page is only accessible with the provided ixsl functions and wasn't aware that Xpath can be used as well. That is why I haven't used the XSLT and XSLT-3.0 tags you edited in, I thougt they would mislead. Thank you for getting me on track.

Still your expression didn't catch it all, because I wanted to use it in a function where no context node is present. I ended up with
 
ixsl:page()//*[@id eq $id][contains-token(@class, 'edited')]

Comment: @Andreas, does `ixsl:page()/id($id)[contains-token(@class, 'edited')]` work as well?

Comment: @Andreas, it seemed to me like a shorter alternative to `ixsl:page()//*[@id eq $id]`, if Saxon in the HTML5 context uses `id` for the DOM elements, which I think it does.

Comment: https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/index.html#!conformance/xslt30 says: "fn:id() and element-with-id(): These functions select those elements returned by the DOM method getElementById()".

Comment: @Martin Honnen: I see that there's a lot more to discover. Thank you!